# Will accessing user email cause app to be rejected

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

The Apple guidelines state:

> **17.1 Privacy**
>   Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and
>   providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected.

My app is fully dependent on the user's email. Will that cause my app to be rejected? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that at some point the user has to enter his email address into a form in your app. Why not just have text explaining briefly what it will be used for, and that by entering it he is giving permission for it to be used?

I'm pretty sure that covers the privacy guideline.

Comment: ok i have explainedv ok.then how i set permission?

Comment: Use the fact that they have given their email address as permission. Just having the explanation should be enough for you to be safe :)

Answer (score 2):

Many many apps rely on email addresses for longins and all kinds of other things.  Taks a look at a few you have and see how they address privacy.  At absolute most you will need to include a little text explaining exactly what you will be doing with the email address.

And here's the thing about being rejected.  Its not the end of the world.  In a case like this, if you got rejected Apple would give you an explaination and what they want from you and you would add whatever statement they requested and you'd re-submit and be on your way.